# kendoDraggable handle inside div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui

I have an issue with a div that own kendoDraggable and jQuery resizable. When I resize, the drag'n'drop event is fired, so I have hint and stop event with the resize.
My goal is to limit the kendoDraggable with a handle as resizable, but I don't manage to init event on this handle and fired the move on the whole div.

Here the generated html code on div to move

```
<div id="vignette_4" class="vignette vignetteFemme ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; top: 514px; left: 298px; width: 153px;">
<span class="libelleVignette">Raymonde BIDOCHON 22/08/1978 11110011</span>
<img src="Content/images/info_rhombus.png" class="detailVignette">
<div class="draggable" data-role="draggable" style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 15px; width: 123px; height: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="LitId" value="11">
<input type="hidden" id="HospitId" value="1326">
<input type="hidden" id="HospiDateDebut" value="/Date(1388444400000)/">
<input type="hidden" id="HospiPeriodeDebut" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="HospiDateFin" value="/Date(1388444400000)/">
<input type="hidden" id="HospiPeriodeFin" value="3">
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have added a div with class "draggable" inside main div "vignette". This is initialised by

```
$(".draggable").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (vignette) {
        var v = vignette.clone();
        v.removeClass();
        var w = $(vignette).width();
        v.css({
            "border":"1px dashed gray",
            "width": w + "px"
        });
        return v;
    },
    cursorOffset: { top: 5, left: 5 }
});
```

But only the handler is moved.

Answer (score 0):

As it is OK to answer to my question, and as it can be useful to next here the answer :)

Move the hint to parent and it's working

```
$(".draggable").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (vignette) {
        var v = $(vignette).parent().clone();
        v.removeClass();
        var w = v.width();
        v.css({
            "border":"1px dashed gray",
            "width": w + "px"
        });
        return v;
    },
    cursorOffset: { top: 5, left: 5 }
});
```